# SparkR 1.6 callJMethod returns empty environment

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have recently moved from SparkR 1.5.2 to 1.6.0. I am doing some experiments using SparkR:::newJObject("java.util.HashMap") and I notice the behaviour has changed. Version 1.6.0 now returns an "environment" instead of a "jobj":

```
> print(class(SparkR:::newJObject("java.util.HashMap")))  # SparkR 1.5.2
[1] "jobj"
```

versus

```
> print(class(SparkR:::newJObject("java.util.HashMap")))  # SparkR 1.6.0
[1] "environment"
```

Moreover, the environment returned is apparently empty (when I call `ls()` on the resulting environment, it returns `character(0)`) . This problem only happens with some Java classes. I am not able to say exactly which classes cause the problem.

If I try to create an instance of other classes such as `java.util.BitSet`, it works successfully. I thought it might be related with parameterized classes, but it does work successfully with `ArrayList` and with `HashSet`, which take type parameters in both cases.

Any suggestions on this change of behaviour (apart from "do not use private functions" :-)   ) ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is "don't use internal API" better? :) This looks like an expected behavior. Spark SQL `MapType` is represented as R `environment`  and the other way around. 1.5 didn't provide support for complex types (there were multiple issues there) so there was no need for automatic conversion. Now it does.